# T-SQL Query to Select current, previous or next week

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I believe i have a difficult query to compose.

Lets say the below image is part of the resultset.

[image]

I need to write a `query` that will give the current weekdays(Monday-Friday) and previous-week and next-week weekdays if required(based on some parameters(`link button click`) from the front end)

So lets say today is 4th, so it will return me `30, 1, 2, 3, 4`

Below is the table structure. Any suggestions to improve this approach is welcome.

[image]

My final output in a `Gridview` will be something like this.

[image]

Comment: What if today is the 5th or the 6th? How do you define "current week" in those cases?

Comment: if its 5th or 6th then show the next week....like `7th, 8th, 9th 10th, 11th`

Comment: So is it correct that you need a window containing the set of weekdays that contain the given day?

Comment: @Rikalous....yea correct....but it needs to come from that table(image provided in the question).....reason...i will have to store data against it

Comment: Why doesn't your table have a `DATE` column? And do you really need to use that table to generate the set? What are you going to do with the set you return?

Comment: @AaronBertrand...any design corrections are welcome...if i add a date column...how will it help...i have updated my question with the final output where i will put this query to use.

Comment: And is your table already populated with data, like one row for every date, with proper values for `Weekend = 0`? Does the solution need to ignore holidays too?

Comment: @AaronBertrand....yes i populated the Table with data....i can change the data...its the data i created....and no...i just need to ignore the weekends and not the holidays.

Comment: Add a DATE column. Much more useful than the individual parts. And the result set should be a single-column set of all the dates - transforming it to be in the grid view format you show is a job for the grid view, not the query, IMHO.

Comment: And is the calendar table *only* being used to derive these dates?

Comment: `DATE` column with the date of the entire year?? is this what you mean?

Comment: The row that has Year = 2013, Month = 9, Day = 30, why not a column that has Date = 2013-09-30?

Comment: yea the calendar table is only used to derive these dates...i have missed a primary key in the table, which i will add it later during the real design. primary key to notify me TASK against dates.

Comment: Well my answer already shows how you can get the set you want without even looking at this table. But if you don't even know what your final table will look like, are you really asking the right question?

Comment: i split the column for simplicity to display it on the grid.

Comment: @AaronBertrand...your answer definitely answers the question without the table. the only reason i built the calendar table was to tally TASK against dates, which is important

Comment: @user2322507 I think you need clarify the question. We're obviously crossing wires here. You can, of course, use my answer as a query and join against it...

Comment: @AaronBertrand....i guess u r right...i need to validate my approach again....but your query did give me some heads up in this issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate SMALLDATETIME; -- Or DATE

SET @CurrentDate = '20131004'

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @CurrentDate) / 7) * 7, 0)  AS FirstDayOfTheWeek,
        DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @CurrentDate) / 7) * 7 + 4, 0)  AS LastDayOfTheWeek
```

Results:

```
FirstDayOfTheWeek       LastDayOfTheWeek
----------------------- -----------------------
2013-09-30 00:00:00.000 2013-10-04 00:00:00.000
```

All days between Monday and Friday:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE;
DECLARE @WeekNum SMALLINT;

SET @CurrentDate = '20131004'
SET @WeekNum = +1; -- -1 Previous WK, 0 Current WK, +1 Next WK

SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, dof.DayNum, fdow.FirstDayOfTheWeek) AS DayAsDateTime
FROM    (VALUES (DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @CurrentDate) / 7) * 7 + @WeekNum*7, 0)))  fdow(FirstDayOfTheWeek)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)) dof(DayNum)

/*
DayAsDateTime
-----------------------
2013-10-07 00:00:00.000
2013-10-08 00:00:00.000
2013-10-09 00:00:00.000
2013-10-10 00:00:00.000
2013-10-11 00:00:00.000
*/

SELECT  *
FROM
(
SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, dof.DayNum, fdow.FirstDayOfTheWeek) AS DayAsDateTime, dof.DayNum
FROM    (VALUES (DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @CurrentDate) / 7) * 7 + @WeekNum*7, 0)))  fdow(FirstDayOfTheWeek)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)) dof(DayNum)
) src 
PIVOT( MAX(DayAsDateTime) FOR DayNum IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4]) ) pvt

/*
0                       1                       2                       3                       4
----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2013-10-07 00:00:00.000 2013-10-08 00:00:00.000 2013-10-09 00:00:00.000 2013-10-10 00:00:00.000 2013-10-11 00:00:00.000
*/
```

Comment: What about the optional last week and next week? What about the 3 days in the middle?

Comment: @Bogdan...this is not really what i wanted.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: 3 days in the middle ?

Comment: @Bogdan yes, your original answer returned the Monday and the Friday of the current week. The OP clearly stated they wanted Monday *through* Friday. Tuesday (1) + Wednesday (1) + Thursday (1) = 3.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean.....your query looks good enough for me now...will rethink about my approach...i will mark this as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I originally interpreted the question: give me the dates for the current week, and optionally the previous and next week. My solution there would be the same regardless of whether you already have a table full of dates (oddly with no `DATE` column):

```
-- these are your unmentioned parameters
DECLARE @include_previous_week BIT = 1, @include_next_week BIT = 1;


SET DATEFIRST 1; -- Monday

DECLARE @today DATE = SYSDATETIME();
DECLARE @wd SMALLINT = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @today);
SET @wd -= CASE WHEN @wd < 6 THEN 0 ELSE 7 END;

;WITH n AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (5) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT the_date = DATEADD(DAY, rn-@wd, @today) FROM n
UNION ALL 
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, rn-7-@wd, @today) FROM n
WHERE @include_previous_week = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, rn+7-@wd, @today) FROM n
WHERE @include_next_week = 1
ORDER BY the_date;
```

Comment: @aaron....lets say my on Previous Button Click, it shows the previous week data. And what if click the Previous Button again, will it go one more week behind??

Comment: @user2322507 your button click would have to maintain state and pass the current (or selected) date in. The code above simply uses today's date as the argument.